# How to set multiple rectangle on google map using api V3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i want to show multiple rectangle on google map. where rectangle's south-west and north-east coordinate fetch from database which i added to database whenever user drew rectangle on map and afterwards help of that coordinate display rectangle

here below the code init() function. in which i am able to display one rectangle but i want multiple so please help me how can i achieve that

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452, -78.5389),
        zoom: 9
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);


        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.9602803542957, -75.179443359375),
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299008636755, -74.00390625)

        );

        var rectangle=new google.maps.Rectangle({
              bounds:bounds,
              strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
                strokeWeight : 3.5,
                fillColor : '#926239',
                fillOpacity : 0.6
              });

            rectangle.setMap(map);

}
```

below code is for draw rectangle on map

```
function drawRec() {

        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingMode : google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
            drawingControl : true,
            drawingControlOptions : {
                position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE ]
            },
            rectangleOptions : {
                strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
                strokeWeight : 3.5,
                fillColor : '#926239',
                fillOpacity : 0.6,
                editable: false,
              draggable: false
            }   
        });

        // Loading the drawing Tool in the Map.
        drawingManager.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'rectanglecomplete',getlatlong);


}
```

In addition i also want to delete specific rectangle from map so please help me which function is used for that Like where user click on specific rectangle and popup come out with delete button

Comment: Can't you just create another rectangle the same way you created the first one?? In a loop or whatever suits your needs? To delete a rectangle use `setMap(null)` instead of `setMap(map)`.

Comment: Btw. your question is **too broad**. As a quick note, you mention users drawing shapes and shapes stored in your database. I think you should take 2 different approaches here: 1) Let the user draw shapes (drawingManager) and 2) Draw shapes stored in the database ([Rectangle class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this one will help you

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452, -78.5389),
        zoom: 9
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);


        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.9602803542957, -75.179443359375),
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299008636755, -74.00390625)

        );

        var rectangle=new google.maps.Rectangle({
              bounds:bounds,
              strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
                strokeWeight : 3.5,
                fillColor : '#926239',
                fillOpacity : 0.6
              });

            rectangle.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function() {
            var contentString = '<br/><b>Hiiii</b>';
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }); 

        /*-------create another bounds ---------------*/    
        var bounds1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.9602803542957, -75.179443359375),
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299008636755, -74.00390625)

        );

        var rectangle1=new google.maps.Rectangle({
              bounds:bounds1,
              strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
                strokeWeight : 3.5,
                fillColor : '#926239',
                fillOpacity : 0.6
              });

            rectangle1.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle1, 'click', function() {
            var contentString1 = '<br/><b>Hiiii</b>';
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString1);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }); 

}
```

i dont know in which language in you would implement it but if you have dynamic data then you can apply here for loop (as like in php) instead of declare bounds and bounds1

Comment: do you have a for loop example?

Comment: do you want multiple rectangle on map ?

Comment: send me your mail id. i will send you loop example